# Quick basic Spring question about @ConditionalOnProperty and @ImportResource

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a very basic and quick question about the use of @ConditionalOnProperty and @ImportResource annotations.

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(value="module.enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)
@ImportResource(locations={"classpath:/cnf/myconf.xml"})
public class ConfigA {

}
```

If the condition is not met (that is the module.enable property is set to false in a properties file) then the ConfigA bean will not be loaded but the resources (myconf.xml) will still be imported. Am i right ?

Whether the condition is true or false, the resources will always be loaded. Correct ?
Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the property doesn't meet the condition the whole Spring Bean is not loaded, in this case the `@ImportResource` is not activated at all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However are you sure about that ?

Comment: Yes I am, you can try it yourself. Just remove(rename) the file from the class path and disable the property, it won’t be loaded and won’t harm your application, however, with the property activated it will break the application as the file won’t be present.

Comment: Thanks. I was not certain at all. I figured out that my problem was with the Spring Expression Language. I used a syntax which was incorrect so the ConditionalProperty annotation had never any effect and the XML files were always imported through the ImportResource annotation.

Comment: No problem, it happens! :) could you tag my answer are correct? Thanks in advance!